# Doubling the value

Tags: angular

I have a list of elements. Each of them has a button. When you click on it, the description assigned to each element expands. Each element has a separate description.
Currently, when I click on the description, regardless of the element, it shows me the same description.

```
export class myComponent {
  elements: MyArray[] = [];
  isDisplay: boolean[] = [];

showDesc(index: number) {
  this.isDisplay[index] = !this.isDisplay[index]
}
}
```

```
<div *ngFor="let element of elements; let i = index">
 <div>
  <span>{{ element.range }}</span>
  <button (click)="showDesc(i)">Show element description</button>
  <p *ngIf="isDisplay[i]">{{ description }}</p>
 </div>

<div>
<span *ngIf="elements.length > 1"
<button (click)="loadElements()">load more elements</button>
</span>
</div>
```

When I console.log my showDesc method I got:
In the first case when I opened the description: [true], when close [false]
In the second case
In the second case: when I opened the description: [false, true] or when the first case shows only true - true. It means that the second value is adds what was clicked in 1 option

Comment: can you please share stackblitz?

Answer (score 1):

We can maintain a property `expanded` on each array element, and then toggle this property on click of the button to achieve this functionality!

I did not understand the logic of `markedElementId` so I commented it out!

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
    <div *ngFor="let element of elements; let i = index">
    <!-- <div *ngIf="markedElementId === 0 || markedElementId === element.id"> -->
      <span>{{ element.range }}</span>
      <button (click)="element.expanded = !element.expanded">Show element description</button>
      <p *ngIf="element.expanded">{{ element.description }}</p>
    <!-- </div> -->
    </div>
    <span *ngIf="elements.length > 1">
    <button (click)="loadElements()">load more elements</button>
    </span>
  `,
})
export class App {
  elements: any[] = [
    { range: 1, description: 'qwerty1' },
    { range: 2, description: 'qwerty2' },
    { range: 3, description: 'qwerty3' },
    { range: 4, description: 'qwerty4' },
    { range: 5, description: 'qwerty5' },
  ];
  markedElementId = 0;
  isDisplay: boolean[] = [];

  loadElements() {
    this.markedElementId = 0;
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-xhzjng?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts&template=node&title=Angular%20Starter)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a [ChangeDetection](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef) issue.
You're programatically updating the value of `this.isDisplay`, however it would not immediately update the UI.

To fix the issue try triggering the change detection right after updating it like this:

```
// Import the change detector
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

// ...

// In your consturctor inject the change detector:
constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectionRef) { }

// ...

// Trigger the changes manually like this
showDesc(index: number) {
  this.isDisplay[index] = !this.isDisplay[index]
  this.changeDetectorRef?.detectChanges();
}
```